# Ignoring .env in Azure Web App zip deploy

Tags: azure, security, visual-studio-code, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I deploy my NodeJS web app through VS Code to my azure web app. That works fine, but it also takes the `.env` file, which is for local purposes only. I tried excluding it in `.vscode\settings.json` by adding it to `appService.zipIgnorePattern` like

```
{
    "appService.zipIgnorePattern": [
        "node_modules{,/**}",
        ".vscode{,/**}",
        ".env"
    ]
}
```

[image]

But it is still visible after redeploy in the files section of my VS code azure plugin.

**Update**: I figured the file is indeed excluded, but the one from the original deployment is still there. Is there an option to remove files from previous deployments? This is a Linux hosted NodeJS Web App.

Answer (score 1):

Try mentioning like this,

```
"appService.zipIgnorePattern": [
    "node_modules{,/**}",
    ".vscode{,/**}",
    ".env{,/**}"
 ]
```

Comment: I tried that (just did a deploy with this setting), but the file remains in the list after refresh (I added a screenshot to the original question)

Comment: I figured already the initial exclusion worked, but the issue is, that the original file is still present. Is there a way to remove "old" files on every deployment? I have not found a setting for that.

Comment: if you are using azure devops, you can do it via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46801799/how-to-clean-up-wwwroot-folder-on-the-target-azure-websites-windows-server-befor

Comment: I'm using VS Code to deploy and the target is Linux, so this is unfortunately not applicable to my context.

Comment: That does not matter

Comment: How could I set that parameter? There is no such option in the deploy process in VS code. I have not found any setting to set that.