# Azure - Proper way to deploy using Azure Local Git - wwwroot folder doesn't have the same contents as Azure Local Git

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am deploying our NodeJS application to our Azure App service using Azure's local git. What I am basically doing is making our CICD pipeline git commit our changes and do a force push to Azure's Local Git. Then, Azure will build the application from the committed files, which seems to be working fine.

But today, I have made a shocking discovery, after couple of weeks of deployment, the files in the `wwwroot` folder does not match the files in the Local Git Repo. The files that do not exist anymore in the Local Git repo are still in the `wwwroot` folder

For example, the git repo contains the following files under `prisma/migrations`

[image]

But in the Azure App service `wwwroot` folder, the same directory contains more than that:

[image]

So, these files are actually from previous deployments that do not exist in the latest version of the `master` branch of the Local Git.

Upon looking at their deployment step, I learned that they are simply copying whatever files are created in their deployment "Oryx/Kudu" deployment step into the `wwwroot` folder without checking if there should be files needed to be deleted:

[image]

If this is the case with this approach, is there a proper way to do this?
Or is there a quick way to clean the existing `wwwroot` folder first before their deployer copy the files?

Hope somebody can help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the ***Azure App Service Deploy*** task in Azure DevOps Pipeline to deploy your application and select ***Web Deploy*** method option, there is an additional option to ***Remove Additional Files at Destination***.

[image]

If you check this option, the deployment process will remove any files at the destination where there is no corresponding file in the package that is being deployed.

In other words, it'll remove any left-over files from a previous deployment that are no longer required.

Please refer to the similar ticket: [How to clean up `wwwroot` folder on the target Azure Websites Windows Server before each deployment in VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46801799/how-to-clean-up-wwwroot-folder-on-the-target-azure-websites-windows-server-befor).

Comment: are there other options I can have without having to setup Azure DevOps?